# How best to work with arbitrary Javascript data objects in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I'm working on a Typescript tool for maintaining state that will receive data as JSON objects and updates to those objects. What I want to be able to do is to combine those objects. Most of the time I expect updates to existing properties but it will also be additions. I will not know the structure of these objects at design time.

So for example I might start from an object like:

```
{
    "kitchen": {
         "door": "closed",
         "cooker": "off",
         "objects": [ "saucepan", "fork", "chopping board", "fresh coriander"]
         "people": {}
    }
}
```

Then I get a series of updates that look like this:

```
  // update 1 
   { 
       "kitchen": { 
              "door": "open";
        }
    }

  // update 2
    {  
        "kitchen" : {
              "people": { "basil": { "wearing": ["hat", "glasses"], "carrying": [] } }
        }
    }

  // update 3
   
    {  
        "kitchen" : {
              "people": { "basil": { "carrying": [ "fork" ] } }
             "objects": [ "saucepan", "chopping board", "fresh coriander"]
        }
    }
```

And so on.

By the end of this process I want my object to look like this:

```
{
    "kitchen": {
         "door": "open",
         "cooker": "off",
          "people": { "basil": { "wearing": ["hat", "glasses"],  "carrying": [ "fork" ] } }
         "objects": [ "saucepan", "chopping board", "fresh coriander"]
    }
}
```

I know these will be pure data objects that are coming into the system and leaving it as JSON.

What I want to be able to do is to walk the structure of the object and identify what has changed and what has been updated. This is super-easy to do in Javascript but TypeScript loves to have everything as a structured interface and I simply won't have those interfaces available in this module. Also they don't really matter, as long as properties get added when they are new and updated when they already exist.

My question is: What is the best way to approach this in Typescript? I'm looking for a way of parsing out the objects so I can treat them as nested dictionaries and compare them accordingly or a recommendation for an existing module in NPM that I can use. I wouldn't be surprised if there is an existing module for this purpose that I couldn't find.

Comment: i.e. you need JSON diff basically? (if yes, comment back, and google for json diff npm)

Comment: What I need is a JSON merge, but the underlying logic for a diff is much the same, I guess if I search through some tools for that it should give me ideas for how to answer this. As I said, it's _very easy_ to do this in Javascript, much more awkward in Typescript. To the point I'm wondering whether I just need to tweak my ts.config to let me do this in Javascript instead. But if there is a good idiomatic Typescript way to do it, I'd prefer to find that.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have come to is pretty much just going into Javascript using `any` typed objects, so I have a function like this:

```
public deepUpdate(original: any, update: any): Object {
    for (let attr in update) {
        if (original.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            let novel = update[attr];
            let orig = original[attr];
            if (orig instanceof Object) {
                if (Array.isArray(orig)) {
                    original[attr] = novel;
                } else {
                    original[attr] = this.deepUpdate(orig, novel);
                }
            } else {
                original[attr] = novel;
            }
        } else {
            original[attr] = update[attr];
        }
    }
    return original;
}
```

It doesn't do any serious comparison of arrays - there's no kind of value-wise comparison, which works for my use case but might not suit everyone - but it solves the problem in a basic way.